# Map vs FlatMap in Spring Web Flux and Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux

I have been working on a sample reactive web api using Spring Boot 2.0.1 and its Webflux library. I have been looking at examples from online to try to build it, but I am stumped on two things. Below are the two questions I have.

1. How do I return a Flux of Response Entities, when I try I get an error saying that only a Single Response Entity can be returned. Below is my current code.

```java
    @Service
    public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {
    
        @Autowired
        private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    
        @Override
        public Flux<Movie> list(){
            return movieRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
    
    @RestController
    public class MovieRestController {
    
        @Autowired
        private MovieService movieService;
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/movies")
        public Flux<Movie> list() {
    
            return movieService.list();
        }
    }
```

2. When I Update an object I use a flatMap to update the object saved in Mongo, and then a Map to turn it to a Response Entity. My question is why am I using flatMap here instead of map? I derived this code from online examples, but no example explained the use of flatMap. I would like to understand why it is being used here. Below is the code.

```java
    @Service
    public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {
    
        @Autowired
        private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Movie> update(String id, MovieRequest movieRequest) {
    
           return movieRepository.findById(id).flatMap(existingMovie -> {
    
               if(movieRequest.getDescription() != null){
                   existingMovie.setDescription(movieRequest.getDescription());
               }
               if(movieRequest.getRating() != null){
                   existingMovie.setRating(movieRequest.getRating());
               }
               if(movieRequest.getTitle() != null) {
                   existingMovie.setTitle(movieRequest.getTitle());
               }
    
               return movieRepository.save(existingMovie);
    
           });
        }
    }
    
    @RestController
    public class MovieRestController {
    
        @Autowired
        private MovieService movieService;
    
        @PutMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
        public Mono<ResponseEntity<Movie>> update(
                @PathVariable("movieId") final String movieId,
                @RequestBody final MovieRequest movieRequest) {
    
            return movieService.update(movieId, movieRequest)
                    .map(m -> new ResponseEntity<>(m, HttpStatus.OK))
                    .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The response of an HTTP Request is unique. All you can do is to send a `Flux` or `Mono` as the body of the response and use a `Content-Type` header to let the client know that it can be consumed it as a stream `application/stream+json` or the usual `application/json`.
2. Both `findById(id)` and `movieRepository.save(existingMovie)` return `Mono<Movie>`. If you map it, each event `Movie` passed to the map will return a `Mono<Movie>` so the concatenation of `findById().map(movieRepository.save())` ends up with a `Mono<Mono<Movie>>`. When you flatmap you're basically "merging" all the publishers from the map into a single `Mono`.

Answer (score 8):

map :

```java
    @PutMapping(path="/update/{id}", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Account> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Account account) {
        Mono<Account> accFound = accountRepository.findById(id);
        return accFound.map(acc -> {
            acc.setAccountBalance(account.getAccountBalance());
            return accountRepository.save(acc).block();
            });

    }
```

`map` adds a `Mono` to whatever is returned inside, note here `accountRepository.save(acc)` returns a `Mono`, and if I dont add `block()`, the method `update` ends up returning `Mono<Mono<Account>>` -- compile error in that case.

flatMap :

```java
    @PutMapping(path="/update/{id}", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Account> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Account account) {
        Mono<Account> accFound = accountRepository.findById(id);
        return accFound.flatMap(acc -> {
            acc.setAccountBalance(account.getAccountBalance());
            return accountRepository.save(acc);
            });

    }
```

`flatMap` simply returns whatever is returned inside.

**Hope it helps to understand it a very basic way**